# How to add or change div image with clicked image from modal

Tags: jquery

I need help for add or change div image with clicked image from modal.

I can get clicked image src from modal and image can be added like this:

```
.html("<img src='"+src+"'>");
```

But how can I know I need add to which area? If I use `$(this).html("<img src='"+src+"'>");` this is for modal-body and will not work for wrapper list. If I use `$(".list .item #image").html("<img src='"+src+"'>");` this will not work again reason of same image id. So how can I know modal opened from which div area?

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div id="image">A</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image">B</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"><a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I clicked to B area, modal opening and images listing there. If I clicked to 100x50.png how can I do B area like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div id="image">A</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"><a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
$(".modal-body").on("click", "img", function() {
var src = $(this).attr('src');   
alert("src: "+src);
//$(this).html("<img src='"+src+"'>");
//$(".list .item #image").html("<img src='"+src+"'>");
});
```

My jsfiddle example code here: (all codes)
https://jsfiddle.net/ve86u907/

Comment: You should not have more than one DOM element with the same id in the same document. If you need to target all the _div_ s with _image_ id you should add a common class to all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the item you clicked with a class (notice that i'm using an *image* class instead of an id, as per my previous comment, so you'll have to change your DOM/other code so that instead of using *#image* id you use *.image* class):

```
$(".list .image").click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('source-modal');
    $('#modal-title').html("TEST");
    modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

so that you can set its html when you click on the modal image:

```
$(".modal-body").on("click", "img", function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');   

    $('.list .image.source-modal').html("<img src='"+src+"'>").removeClass('source-modal');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Add class really a good idea for mark clicked item. I changed #image with .image class name and now working very good. https://jsfiddle.net/ctjxya05/